# marginLeft only resets if called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a basic carousel type slidshow, however to get it to work I had to call the following function twice for it to actually set the margin-left property to 0px.

`$("#slide ul").stop().css('marginLeft', '0px');`

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, as I'm new to jquery.

The entire thing can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/xZBZK/

Just the JavaScript for convenience:

```
var offset = 0;
var count;
var width = 500;
var height = 333;
var interval;

$(document).ready(function() {
    count = $("#slide ul").children().length;
    // Add the first image to the end so it loops.
    $("#slide ul").children().first().clone().appendTo("#slide ul");
    start();
});

function nextImage() {
    $("#slide ul").stop();
    offset+=width;
    if(offset / width == count) { 
        $("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700, 'linear', resetImage);
    }
    $("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700);
    return offset;
}

function resetImage() {
    $("#slide ul").stop().css('marginLeft', '0px');
    $("#slide ul").stop().css('marginLeft', '0px');
    offset = 0;
    //start();
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function start() {
    interval = setInterval(nextImage, 3000);
}
```

I'm using **JQuery 1.9.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you are loading two animations into the queue?

```
if(offset / width == count) { 
    $("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700, 'linear', resetImage);
}
$("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700);
```

Maybe you want:

```
if(offset / width == count) { 
    $("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700, 'linear', resetImage);
}else{
    $("#slide ul").animate({'marginLeft':'-'+offset+'px'}, 700);
}
```

I think `.stop()` only stops the current animation and doesn't clear the queue. so its defaulting to the animation before it.

Comment: Man i'm an idiot. Thanks! Just as a side note, is there anyway to stop all animations?

Comment: @Blam sure, per element. `.stop(true,true)`